# How do you delete a key from a dictionary within a list of dictionaries based on a user specified value?

Tags: python

I have figured out how to delete the some values based on the name but additionally if the value is the last index position within the list of dictionaries it does not delete the value. This is the code I have so far.

```
if data[0]['name'] == name:
    del data[0]
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional detail? A sample of the data you are working with, and why the snippet you posted isn't adequate?

Answer (score 0):

The question was very vague, but from what you have asked, you would like to keep all dictionaries that don't satisfy name. This should work:

```
data = [d for d in data if d['name'] != name]
```